# Can't remotely fetch event viewer logs of the logname Security

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been trying to get the event viewer logs of application, security and system and store the output into an xml file. While application and system work just fine I have been having problems with security.

Comment: Are you able to read those logs when you manually login to the target machine with the same credentials?

Comment: @SavindraSingh When I manually log into the machine with the user I get the same error message "Get-WinEvent : Could not retrieve information about the Security log. Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.."

Comment: Add the "BUILTIN\Event Log Readers" group to the following registry key permissions: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security
This key only
Query Value, Enumerate Subkeys, Notify, Read Control. On a domain you can do this using group policy to cover all machines

Comment: @SavindraSingh small info: When I try to read these logs without the Get-WinEvent PowerShell Command and instead use the event viewer to read it works.

Comment: @Scepticalist So I went to the registry key, rightclicked the Security key and clicked on permissions and added the "Event Log Readers" and gave them full control. Unfortunately it still says:
"Get-WinEvent : Could not retrieve information about the Security log. Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized"

Comment: @Scepticalist Nevermind I accidentally added "Event Log" instead of "Event Log Readers". It works now :) Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security event log is secured to machine administrators only.

As you've added your account to the "Event Log Readers" group, you need to add the "BUILTIN\Event Log Readers" group to the following registry key permissions:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security

> This key only

> Query Value, Enumerate Subkeys, Notify, Read Control

On a domain you can do this using group policy to cover all machines:

Group Policy Object Editor: Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings